# Positiveness of a function

Tags: functions, optimization

Consider three $n\times 1$ vectors, $a,b,c$. Each element of $a$ and $c$ is in $[0,1]$. Further, the sum of $a$'s elements is one. Fix $a$ and consider the following problem
$$
P:\hspace{1cm} \max_{b\in \mathbb{R}^n} \min_{c\in [0,1]^{n}}  b^T(a-c)\\
\hspace{1cm}\text{s.t.} \hspace{1cm} b^Tb\leq 1\\
\hspace{1cm}\hspace{1cm} \sum_{k=1}^n c_k=1
$$
where $c_k$ is the $k$-th element of $c$.

**Question:** is the value of $P$ always positive?
I believe so, but I would like to get your confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the minimax theorem we have that
\begin{equation*}
p^* = \sup_{b\in B} \inf_{c\in C} b^\top(a-c) = \inf_{c\in C}\sup_{b\in B}b^\top (a-c),
\end{equation*}
where $B = \{b\in\mathbb{R}^n : b^\top b\le 1\}$ and $C=\{c\in\mathbb{R}^n : 0\le c \le \mathbf{1}_n, ~ \sum_{i=1}^n c_i = 1 \}$. The inner supremum is solved by the dual norm, i.e. for fixed $c$ we have that
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{\|b\|_2 \le 1}b^\top(a-c) = \|a-c\|_2.
\end{equation*}
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
p^* = \inf_{c\in C} \|a-c\|_2.
\end{equation*}
This shows that $p^* \ge 0$, as you suspected. Also, notice that by expanding the squared 2-norm you can solve your problem as the following convex quadratic program:
\begin{align*}
p^* = \inf_{c\in C} (a^\top a - 2a^\top c + c^\top c).
\end{align*}